# Merging Selected Features in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, merge

i tried to merge several polygon into one using "merge selected features" but it's look not perfect because there are some lines left as residual. can anyone help me to solve my problem.
i am using QGIS 2.14 Essen

[image]

The yellow polygon is one, but there are some lines which looks like separated them. and when i open the shp file in arcgis the line still appears

Comment: it looks like they're close but not overlapping, what do they look like when you zoom right in? You could try exploding, snapping and then re-dissolving.

Comment: When i zoomed the feature it's merged, but there are line but not fully separated the polygon. i tried to exploding just 1 polygon separeted but not with the others.
for additional information, when i merge with ArcMap it's perfect merged with others